# GNU g++ 4.9.2 Compilation Error for a find function call

Tags: c++, string, c++11, vector, find

I have StringVec defined as:

```
typedef std::vector<string> StringVec;
```

Variable colnames is defined as:

```
StringVec colnames;
```

And I have a function as below:

```
int colIndex(const string &cn) const {
        StringVec::iterator i1;
        i1 = find(colnames.begin(),colnames.end(),cn);
        return(i1 == colnames.end() ? -1 : (i1 - colnames.begin()));
}
```

When I try to compile with GNU g++ 4.9.2 (C++11), it complains:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'find(std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >::const_iterator, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >::const_iterator, const string&)'
 i1 = find(colnames.begin(),colnames.end(),cn);
```

Even `std::find` couldn't solve this.
Another clue is given by compiler:

```
note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
note:   '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const std::basic_string<char>*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > >' is not derived from 'std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT>'
  i1 = std::find(colnames.begin(),colnames.end(),cn);
```

Any clue?

Comment: @ks1322 No, thst didn't solve, edited my Qs with more clue from compiler

Comment: Have you included the proer headerfile for the find function ? You should create a complete but minimal example that shows the error you have, so other people can just copy/paste and try it for themselves.

Comment: @nos, I added #include <algorithm>, this is perfect now! So many thanks. This was compiling perfectly with earlier version of compiler (non-C++11), good anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the info you gave, I made a minimal example (with the min modifications, did you include the headers?):

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

typedef std::vector<std::string> StringVec;
StringVec colnames;
int colIndex(const std::string &cn) {
        StringVec::iterator i1;
        i1 = std::find(colnames.begin(),colnames.end(),cn);
        return(i1 == colnames.end() ? -1 : (i1 - colnames.begin()));
}

int main() {

        return 0;
}
```

and it compiled just fine with g++ 4.8.4:

```
gsamaras@gsamaras-A15:~$ g++ -Wall px.cpp 
gsamaras@gsamaras-A15:~$
```